# how to write some text in the plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I wrote the following code in matlab for plotting a graph. I have three curves in the same plot. I want to mention the particular class to each curve to which it belongs.How can I do it using same code that i wrote. Code is:

```
  plot(mm,q1(1,:),'b')
    hold on
    plot(mm,q1(2,:),'g')
    plot(mm,q1(3,:),'r')
    plot(mm,q1(4,:),'m')
    xlabel('time(yr)')
    ylabel('probability')
    hold off
```

I want to write 'M1 to M2'in plot corresponding to graph for plot(mm,q1(1,:),'b'). Similarily for other plots 'M1 to M2' , 'M1 to M3' ,'M1 to M4' respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`legend`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html) as follows:

`legend('M1 to M2','M1 to M3','M1 to M4');`

This allows you to label curves.

Comment: how can i also write text using arrow mentioning  particular curve?

Comment: i want to use textarrow.

Comment: @user5179049 - This should generally be asked as a different question.. Take a look at [`annotation` objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html#bt60iko).